# SharpSVN Add local folder to repository location

Tags: c#, .net, sharpsvn

I have an application, much like visual studio, in which you can create a solution out of source control, and then add it to souce control.

I am using SharpSVN, and I cannont figure out how to add a local set of files to the repository URI selected.

Do anyone know of a way to do this in SharpSVN?

Comment: Ah, I just had to stare at it longer. I needed to use client.Import(path, uri, importArgs). Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: `SvnClient.Import()` is the equivalant of `svn import` followd by `svn checkout --force`. You can use `SvnClient.RemoteImport()` if you only want to import the files without creating a working copy.